# ROSのエラー： AttributeError: module 'moveit_commander' has no attribute 'MoveGroupCommander'

Tags: python, python3, linux, ubuntu

タイトルの通り、最近、ros melodic から noetic にロボットでバージョンアップしたところ、サンプルコードすら実行できず、エラーが報告される理由がわかりませんが、このロボットはすでに noetic バージョンをサポートしています。

[image: ターミナルの表示]

```
limlab@limlab:~$ rosrun sciurus17_examples pick_and_place_right_arm_demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/limlab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sciurus17_examples/pick_and_place_right_arm_demo.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/limlab/catkin_ws/src/sciurus17_ros/sciurus17_examples/scripts/pick_and_place_right_arm_demo.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/limlab/catkin_ws/src/sciurus17_ros/sciurus17_examples/scripts/pick_and_place_right_arm_demo.py", line 15, in main
    robot = mmoveit_commander.RobotCommander()
AttributeError: module 'moveit_cammander' has no attribute 'RobotCommander'
limlab@limlab:~$
```

コードは以下の通りです。

```
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import geometry_msgs.msg
import rosnode
import actionlib
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler
from control_msgs.msg import (GripperCommandAction, GripperCommandGoal)


def main():
    rospy.init_node("sciurus17_pick_and_place_controller")
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    arm = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("r_arm_waist_group")
    arm.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.1)
    gripper = actionlib.SimpleActionClient("/sciurus17/controller1/right_hand_controller/gripper_cmd", GripperCommandAction)
    gripper.wait_for_server()
    gripper_goal = GripperCommandGoal()
    gripper_goal.command.max_effort = 2.0

    rospy.sleep(1.0)

    print("Group names:")
    print(robot.get_group_names())

    print("Current state:")
    print(robot.get_current_state())

    # アーム初期ポーズを表示
    arm_initial_pose = arm.get_current_pose().pose
    print("Arm initial pose:")
    print(arm_initial_pose)

    # 何かを掴んでいた時のためにハンドを開く
    gripper_goal.command.position = 0.9
    gripper.send_goal(gripper_goal)
    gripper.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(1.0))

    # SRDFに定義されている"home"の姿勢にする
    arm.set_named_target("r_arm_waist_init_pose")
    arm.go()
    gripper_goal.command.position = 0.0
    gripper.send_goal(gripper_goal)
    gripper.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(1.0))

    # 掴む準備をする
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.25
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.3
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()  # 実行

    # ハンドを開く
    gripper_goal.command.position = 0.7
    gripper.send_goal(gripper_goal)
    gripper.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(1.0))

    # 掴みに行く
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.25
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.13
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()  # 実行

    # ハンドを閉じる
    gripper_goal.command.position = 0.4
    gripper.send_goal(gripper_goal)
    gripper.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(1.0))

    # 持ち上げる
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.25
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.3
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()                            # 実行

    # 移動する
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.4
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.3
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()  # 実行

    # 下ろす
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.4
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.13
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()  # 実行

    # ハンドを開く
    gripper_goal.command.position = 0.7
    gripper.send_goal(gripper_goal)
    gripper.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration(1.0))

    # 少しだけハンドを持ち上げる
    target_pose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
    target_pose.position.x = 0.4
    target_pose.position.y = 0.0
    target_pose.position.z = 0.2
    q = quaternion_from_euler(3.14/2.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # 上方から掴みに行く場合
    target_pose.orientation.x = q[0]
    target_pose.orientation.y = q[1]
    target_pose.orientation.z = q[2]
    target_pose.orientation.w = q[3]
    arm.set_pose_target(target_pose)  # 目標ポーズ設定
    arm.go()  # 実行

    # SRDFに定義されている"home"の姿勢にする
    arm.set_named_target("r_arm_waist_init_pose")
    arm.go()

    print("done")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        if not rospy.is_shutdown():
            main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: ここ [MoveIt » Tutorials » Move Group Python Interface](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) の [The Entire Code](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html#the-entire-code) に書かれているソースコードとは違いが大きいようですが、例えば`moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)`が呼ばれていないですね。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。今試しにmoveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)を入れますと、以下のようなエラーが出てきます。[ERROR] [1663153184.466858269]: Client [/move_group] wants topic /move_group/goal to have datatype/md5sum [moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal/152e336e337dce7cbe639f1bd9c65def], but our version has [moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal/b7138704cefd43a8dd9758d697350b85]. Dropping connection.

Comment: 紹介サイトで表示対象の版数を変えると色々変わる部分が多いようなので、それぞれの版数で環境設定などに違いがある可能性があるのでは？ エラーメッセージに`md5sum`とか`but our version has`とかがあるので、もしかしたら細かい版数が少し違っただけで環境をごっそり入れ替える必要があるのかもしれませんね。

Comment: わかりました。やってみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみにエラーメッセージによると、`.../catkin_ws/devel/lib/...`の下と`.../catkin_ws/src/...`の下の両方に同じ名前の`pick_and_place_right_arm_demo.py`があって、途中で入れ替わると言うか別の物が実行されているようですが、それは正常な動作なのでしょうか？

Comment: それはこのコード自身が色々のバッケージを使っていますので、問題ないですね。今日中moveitを全部アンインストールして、もう一度インストールしたら、問題が解決しました。色々提案してくれて誠にありがとうございました！